# Bounds for $D = {x^2+y^2\leq4}$ vs $C = {x^2+y^2=4}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

a.) A circular metal wire $C$ in the $xy$-plane id described by $C = {x^2+y^2=4}$ and has density $\sigma(x,y) = x +7$ at the point $(x,y)$. Find the mass of $C$

b.) A circular metal disk $D$ in the $xy$-plane id described by $D = {x^2+y^2\leq4}$ and has density $\sigma(x,y) = x +7$ at the point $(x,y)$. Find the mass of $D$

For a.)

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2} r^2cos(\theta) + 7r drd\theta$$

For b.)

This is what was messing me up. Wouldn't the bounds be the same? What is the difference between bounds for $D = {x^2+y^2\leq4}$ vs $C = {x^2+y^2=4}$ ?

Comment: In one case you are integrating over a disk, in the other you are integrating on a circunference, i.e., only over the boundary of the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are considering only a circumference, so you have linear density, i.e. mass per unit of lenght. Thus, if we set $x=2\cos\theta$ and $y=2\sin\theta$, we have:
$$ m = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta+7)2d\theta$$
In the second case, you are considering a full disk, so you have a superficial density, i.e. mass per unit of area. Thus, using the same change of variables:
$$ m = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}(r\cos\theta+7)rdr d\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful